# Is Presentation API supported on android version 11 or greater?

Tags: android

I have a project using secondary display, using [Presentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation) API.
It works with emulator with Android 10, device with Android 9 but not with emulator with Android 11 or 12.

On emulator, I create secondary display as shown on picture: [image]

Here my activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var presentation: Presentation?  = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val displayManager = getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager
        if (displayManager.displays != null && displayManager.displays.size > 1) {
            val display = displayManager.displays[1]
            presentation = TestPresentation(this, display)
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        presentation?.show()
        super.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        presentation?.hide()
        super.onPause()
    }
}
```

And my presentation

```
class TestPresentation(context: Context, display: Display): Presentation(context,display) 
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        setContentView(R.layout.presentation_layout)
    }
}
```

On Android 11 or greater, I've got this error:

> 2022-03-21 22:44:55.458 3563-3563/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
> main
> Process: com.example.testpresentation2, PID: 3563
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.testpresentation2/com.example.testpresentation2.MainActivity}:
> android.view.WindowManager$InvalidDisplayException: Unable to add
> window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@9b166b1 -- the specified display
> can not be found
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4444)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4476)
> at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$InvalidDisplayException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@9b166b1 -- the
> specified display can not be found
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:1096)
> at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:409)
> at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:109)
> at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:340)
> at android.app.Presentation.show(Presentation.java:257)
> at com.example.testpresentation2.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.kt:35)

Comment: If it was deprecated, the docs would say so, Google is good about that.  However permissions may have changed, or you may have to do some other additional work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in AVD/Emulator.

Emulator extended control needs to support passing flags for the display setup. A display needs to explicitly specify FLAG_PRESENTATION in order to be a valid target for a presentation.

Issue open on google tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227218392